# How to detect Remote Desktop Session Host using registry?

Tags: windows-services, registry, windows-server-2008-r2

I need to detect if Remote Desktop Session Host is installed in windows server 2008 using registry data as part of the prerequisite checker for our product. Earlier it was known as terminal service which could be detected using the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Terminal Server\TSEnabled key but now this key "TSEnabled" is no more part of the registry.

Answer (score 0):

It seems **TSEnabled** key is no longer present in Windows 2008 server. There's not much information about it, except for these:
http://forums.techarena.in/small-business-server/1015603.htm 
http://msmvps.com/blogs/bradley/archive/2008/05/20/attaching-a-windows-2008-terminal-server-box-to-a-sbs-2003-server.aspx

Did you try using **fDenyTSConnections** key? Does this key serve your purpose?
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722151.aspx 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd184089.aspx